# How to set a timeout for Firefox OS TCP Sockets

Tags: javascript, sockets, firefox, tcp, firefox-os

I am working on a [[image]firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os) app that tries to connect to a list of IP's in sequence through the [TCP Socket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket).

However, I would like to **close the socket** if it doesn't connect within a few seconds, and also if the connection is inactive for more than a few seconds.

Example:

```
var socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(IP, port);
//would like to set timeout for connection here
socket.onopen = function(event){
    var serviceRequest = new Object();
    serviceRequest.type = "myService";
    var sendStr = JSON.stringify(serviceRequest);
    sendStr+="\n";
    sendStr = sendStr.toString('utf-8');
    socket.send(sendStr);
    //and would like a timeout for receiving data here
    socket.ondata = function(event){
        //etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify a timeout as far as I know. If you want to specify a timeout, you should use the usual javascript `setTimeout`, store its id.

Use the `onopen` event on the TCPSocket object to cancel the timeout. If the timeout is triggered. You can call the `close` method on the socket.

```
var socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(IP, port);

var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    socket.close()
}, timeoutDuration)

//would like to set timeout for connection here
socket.onopen = function(event){
    // Prevent from timingout if open
    clearTimeout(timeout)

    var serviceRequest = new Object();
    serviceRequest.type = "myService";
    var sendStr = JSON.stringify(serviceRequest);
    sendStr+="\n";
    sendStr = sendStr.toString('utf-8');
    socket.send(sendStr);
    //and would like a timeout for receiving data here
    socket.ondata = function(event){
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this.